# Firefox font is messed up after update to Firefox 80

Tags: firefox

After updating, the font in the search bar, tabs, and bookmarks are all too big and also not my set font. This problem can be temporarily fixed by deleting .mozilla, but unfortunately it is re-broken after restarting Firefox. It is a real eyesore, can anybody help me out to find the culprit of this? If it helps I'm using GNOME and the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060.

Update: It only appears to take effect after syncing my account and then restarting Firefox, still unsure how to fix

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I found a workaround. Still not entirely sure what caused it, but I fixed it by disabling sync for settings, then deleting .mozilla and setting up Firefox again.

Comment: That is not a fix, that is a workaround.

Comment: @vanadium You're right

Comment: So I suggest you edit your answer and change to "Alright, I found a workaround" :-;

Comment: @vanadium If it makes you feel better